# Edit already minified JavaScript snippet

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have to edit the minified snippet below to:
IF a message (string) is handled by the snippet containing the word **API** then to change the entire message to ****Something went wrong.** Try again later.** Please let me know how I can do this. Thank you!

```
wc_myplugin.BaseGateway.prototype.submit_error = function(t) {
var e = this.get_error_message(t);
e.indexOf("</ul>") < 0 && (e = '<div class="' + function() {
    var t = "woocommerce-MyPlugin";
    return this.is_current_page("checkout") && (t += " woocommerce-MyPlugin-checkout"), t
}.bind(this)() + '"><ul class="woocommerce-error"><li>' + e + "</li></ul></div>");
t = o(document.body).triggerHandler("wc_myplugin_submit_error", [e, t, this]);
e = void 0 === t ? e : t, this.submit_message(e)
```

Comment: Change `e` in `<li>' + e + "</li>` to your string?

Comment: @RickardElimää - I only want to change the message to `Something went wrong. Try again later.` only if a message handled by the snippet is containing the word `API` otherwise all other messages shouldn't be changed. If I change `e` to  `Something went wrong. Try again later.` then all messages handled by the snippet will be `Something went wrong. Try again later.` `e` is not always the same. I'm getting the error messages from an API.

Comment: @RickardElimää - so basically what I want to do is IF `e` contains `API` word then change the message to `Something went wrong. Try again later.`. Is there any way I can do that? Thank you a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I added `var eMessage = e.contains('API') ? 'Something went wrong. Try again later' : e;` on the third row. Basically, checks if the error message contains "API" (capital letters). If so, the error message is replaced, otherwise it remains the same.

```
wc_myplugin.BaseGateway.prototype.submit_error = function(t) {
var e = this.get_error_message(t);
var eMessage = e.contains('API') ? 'Something went wrong. Try again later' : e;
e.indexOf("</ul>") < 0 && (e = '<div class="' + function() {
    var t = "woocommerce-MyPlugin";
    return this.is_current_page("checkout") && (t += " woocommerce-MyPlugin-checkout"), t
}.bind(this)() + '"><ul class="woocommerce-error"><li>' + eMessage + "</li></ul></div>");
t = o(document.body).triggerHandler("wc_myplugin_submit_error", [e, t, this]);
e = void 0 === t ? e : t, this.submit_message(e)
```